# dynamically change the number of partition during runtime

Tags: apache-spark

If I want to dynamically change the number of partition during runtime, which parameter and which file should I make some modification for the Spark source code. I don't want to use the coalesce or repartition operation for the experiment's need.

Comment: are you looking to have the same partition for all the DF? else I don't think there is an option apart form `coalesce` or `repartition`

Comment: Yep, so i am trying to modify the source code of Spark